# Is it possible to use Macbook with 0% health?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Is it possible to use macbook pro if the battery is at 0% health?
It is 1% at the moment and work fine when plugged, but what about if it goes to 0% ?

Comment: Just curious: How many cycles does it have and what model is it?

Comment: MacBook pro mid 2010 15'' , 591 cycles , original max 6900 mAh, current 46mAh

Comment: This post http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116193/how-to-disable-the-speedstep-when-using-macbook-pro-without-a-battery may also be of relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter when you plug it in. You can even remove (not advised though) the battery and still use it when the adapter is plugged in. I can imagine the battery does not work properly (or even work at all) when it hits the 0%