# How to disable the SpeedStep when using MacBook Pro (revisited)?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance

First of all, the specs:

- MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011)
- OS X 10.12.6 (Sierra)
- 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB RAM

I use this laptop in permanent clamshell mode, as though it were a desktop, with many externals, via powered USB hubs, etc.

**The Problem:**

About a year ago, my battery health fell below a point where SpeedStep was triggered, even when plugged in, and the CPU was generally crippled to 800Mhz.

In my laziness, I continued to use the computer in this fashion for about a year. (You can still do a lot with quad-core 800Mhz.)

I finally installed a healthy battery. However, the CPU is still operating at SpeedStep speeds. I've rebooted a couple of times; the 2.2Ghz processor is still running at 800Mhz.

It seems that my CPU is "stuck" on SpeedStep setting (even though the power is healthy and adequate). How can I resume normal speeds?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to disable the SpeedStep when using MacBook Pro without a battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116193/how-to-disable-the-speedstep-when-using-macbook-pro-without-a-battery?rq=1) or [How to disable SpeedStep/XCPM on Macbook Pro 11,1 OSX 10.10.2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197914/how-to-disable-speedstep-xcpm-on-macbook-pro-11-1-osx-10-10-2?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried resetting SMC, PRAM and NVRAM?